# could not find file Error if file exists c#

Tags: c#

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
Attachment data = new Attachment(@"\\MYPC\Share\FinalReport.html");
message.Attachments.Add(data);
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

This Code has worked fine for the last week. But today I got an exception as it could not find file: *\MYPC\Share\FinalReport.html*. I tried for an hour in different ways then I restarted my system. Again its Worked fine.

Key point: I didn't shutdown or restart my PC for the past week.

Comment: Have you checked whether the file actually exists where it is supposed to?

Comment: Is the file actually there if you browse to that folder?

Comment: The exception seems pretty self-explantory, the file isn't there, or isn't accessible...

Comment: One possible reason is that you need to authenticate with that share and somehow that authentication was "lost".

Comment: Could be one of a number of things Networking, and Security would be my top guesses.

Comment: 100 % File is in Location. i can access it manually.i have tested with others machine also . i can able to open it . i have undo my changes then restarted . it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much to go on with your question really, however, if I had to guess I would say it's probably an issue with your network access. It looks as though your accessing the file on a network share so if you are losing connection at some point that would explain the `FileNotFoundException`. It's not uncommon for network access to become "unavailable" at peak times i.e. when your network is at it's busiest.